# JSF Controller not support post method in spring

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I'm integreating JSF and Primefaces with Spring, I want to handle navigation with JSF and ManagedBean as controller but for some reason I´m not able to send request from JSF view to ManagedBean controller, I getting error: **"method 'POST' not allowed"** I suppose this is because in a Spring context I need to specify @PostMapping but my controller is a ManagedBean how can I solve this problem. Thank in advance.

View code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Bholamundo-jsf-cdi</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view locale="#{languageController.locale}" />
    <ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" template="./WEB-INF/plantillas/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:outputLabel for="username" value="#{msgs['username']}:" /></td>
                        <td><p:inputText id="username" required="true" value="#{userLoginView.username}" /></td>
                        <td><p:message for="username" class="errorMessage" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msgs['password']}:" /></td>
                        <td><p:password id="password" required="true" value="#{userLoginView.password}" /></td>
                        <td><p:message for="password" class="errorMessage" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><h:commandButton id="logIn" action="#{userLoginView.login}" value="#{msgs['logIn']}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

ManagedBean code:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserLoginView {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public UserLoginView() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.username = "";
        this.password = "";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String login() {
        System.out.println("beans.backing.UserLoginView.login()->username: " + username + ", password: " + password);
        // FacesMessage message = null;
        if (username != null && username.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
            // message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", username);
            // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            System.out.println("log in success");
            return "indexLogged";
        } else {
            System.out.println("ok es por aqui");
            // message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Loggin Error",
            // "Invalid credentials");
            System.out.println("mensaje instanciado correctamente");
            // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            System.out.println("Faces Context obtenido correctamente");
            return "index";
        }
        // PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <!--No se necesita agregar la extension del archivo, para configurar los 
            mensajes -->
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>mensajes</base-name>
            <var>msgs</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <!--cambio de textos de validadores -->
        <message-bundle>errorMessages</message-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: The error you get is in no way related to JSF or PrimeFaces. Debug... Check where the error is thrown. Might be a servlet of yours of Spring or whatever but not a managed bean.

Comment: And your title is remarkable `Bholamundo-jsf-cdi` ;-) Better to use cdi instead of jsf managed beans

Comment: I know my problem is not releated with JSF is just a Spring config, I'm sure about it, the problem is that I don´t know how fixed. And my title is find :P

Comment: Only one thing to do then...[mcve]

Comment: I don't see any Spring code in your question.. How does it relate with Spring?

Comment: You can´t see any spring code in my example because this is the view part and is all in JSF, however I will update the example with the web.xml and faces-config.xml

Comment: What Controller do You mean. JSP terminology doesn't have direct such concep. Pls use JSF terms.

Comment: what is "JSF and Primefaces integration by Spring"? They don't require any extra integration.

Comment: You right, JSF do not have such a term like controller, I just was trying to explain the roll of the classes, and when I say integration I mean to integrate JSF UI Framework with Spring

Comment: On the margin, i have minimised use of Spring in my Java code across years, and now I'm Spring-free. Maybe it was a King (like Elvis), Spring had positive role in ancient J2EE years (replaces/concures with bad J2EE API), by (my opinion) not in 2018 (strong position of JEE 7 with very good API and now JEE 8). Hard to imagine why require spring.